# FileMaker XML Web Publishing XML error

Tags: php, xml, filemaker

```
$FM_CONNECT = array(
    'DB_FILE'   =>  'webaccess'
);
require_once "__app/dbConnect/FM.php";
require_once "__app/environmentSettings/environmentSettings.php";

$layout = 'webAccess';

$findCommand =& $fm->newFindCommand($layout);
$findCommand->addFindCriterion('AccountName', $_POST['username']);
$result = $findCommand->execute();

if(FileMaker::isError($result)){
    FMExit(array(
        'code'  =>  1,
        'mes'   =>  $result->getMessage()
    ));
}
$records = $result->getRecords();
```

When I try send some request to FileMaker server it return.
**"XML error: Not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1"**

I haven't change the code for a few weeks and I didn't see this error before.

Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like FileMaker php api. If it is the case, you are missing the connection. If you just omitted the connection code from your code (since you get the error from the server), look at your request and check that XML is well formed. I can't check the request as you did not post it.

Comment: My db connection is inside "require_once '__app/dbConnect/FM.php'" file.
This code works well few year without any error.
I realized that this is not php api problem. In my case it was limit of web publishing connections to FileMaker Server.

Comment: Really? The maximum number of connections for FileMaker server 14 or 15 is 2000. Is it that busy?

Comment: I mean web publishing connecting.

Comment: I am talking about custom web publishing connections and for the last few versions of FMS the limit is 2000 concurrent connections

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the web publishing engine is started and working. I faced this problem already and in my case the `WPE` was stopped suddenly. I started the `WPE` from the admin console and it was fine.